# JMS have javax.jms.InvalidDestinationException when client stop working

Tags: java, exception, jms, spring-jms

I use JMS for sending requests from a client to a server.

My client sends a request to the server. While the server is working with my request, my client stops (network problem) before the server finishes.

When the server is finished, it'll return to the client, but the server can't see the client which sent the request to server, at which point, the server will return an exception in log file.

The exception is :

```
javax.jms.InvalidDestinationException: Cannot publish to a deleted Destination: temp-queue://ID:PC0092-49463-1344231871819-0:0:9 [^]
```

My question is: what do I need to do in this case? Can I catch or disable this exception? And how can I do it?

(Sorry, If my english is not good.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I can fix this problem.
In brokerURL, I added the attribute `jms.watchTopicAdvisories=false`.
Use this attributes to disable advisory monitor.